# RegEx to extract city and state from string AND know when someone leaves out the state part

Tags: php, regex

i have the following code:

```
preg_match("/^(.+)[,\\s]+(.+?)\s*(\d{5})?$/", trim($searchbox), $matches);
list($arr['add'], $arr['city'], $arr['state']) = $matches;

$citystr = trim(str_replace(',', '', $arr['city']));
$statestr = trim($arr['state']);
```

This works great when someone types in "Granite Bay, CA", however i would like to modify it to catch when someone leave out the ", CA" part. So if someone only types "granite Bay", the code above is taking "Bay" as the state - thats no good. It also fails if someone adds a zip to the end like "Granite Bay, CA 00000"

Are there any modifications to this RegEx that i can do to avoid both these senarios?

TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can build a less permissive/more detailed pattern:

```
^\h*([^,\s]+(?:\h+[^,\s]+)*+)\h*(?:,\h*([A-Z]+))?\h*(\d{5})?\h*$
```

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/t0lK4Q/1)

`([^,\s]+(?:\h+[^,\s]+)*+)` catches the city name as: something that doesn't start nor end with whitespaces and eventually in several parts.

`(?:,\h*([A-Z]+))?` makes all the state part optional. Note that I have chosen only uppercase letters for the state, but you can also make it case insensitive, it doesn't matter since the important point is the comma.

As an aside, if you want to be sure of what enter a user, use one field per information (one for the city, one for the state, one for the zip code).

Comment: Thats nice, except it does not work when there is a input like: "folsom,ca" (no space and only 1 words for city)

Comment: @Nugs: No the problem is the case of the state, and as I wrote it, "you can also make it case insensitive". All spaces and additional parts for the city name are already optional.

Comment: Ok, how do i make it so it ignores case entirely?

Comment: Nevermind. Can you double check me on this: ^\h*([^,\s]+(?:\h+[^,\s]+)*+)\h*(?:,\h*([a-z]+))?\h*(\d{5})?$

Comment: @Nugs: in this case if the user write `CA` it will not match. Use the i modifier or use `[a-zA-Z]`

Answer (score 2):

You could go for:

```
^                       # start of the string
(?P<town>[A-Z][^,]+)    # uppercase, followed by not a comma
(?>                     # a non-capturing group
    ,\h*\K              # a comma, horizontal whitespace, \K
    (?P<state>[A-Z]{2}) # two UPPERCASE letters
)?                      # make the whole group optional
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/myZ5Rk/1).
To be sure, you'll likely need some database of towns and states to check against, though (the above expression allows `XY` for a state as well), or as @Casimir points out, use several fields for each information.